# Problems installing umbracoCms in Visual Studio 2019 due to conflicting dependencies

Tags: installation, visual-studio, dependencies

I am trying to install umbracoCms in Visual Studio, but every time I try it gives me errors about dependencies version control.

Windows 7
  VS edition: 2019
  umbracoCms edition: 8.0.1

```
Error: NU1608 Detected package version outside of dependency constraint:  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.1 requires Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design (>=2.1.1 && <2.2.0)  
but version Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design 2.2.0 was resolved.
```

Troubleshooting thus far: I've tried install umbracoCms using the package manager console and the "manage NuGet Package options". I've tried doing the most current version of packages and older ones. I've tried installing dependencies in different orders and with older versions.  When I try building a solution, it fails even with an empty app, saying that `the helper directive is not supported`.